# Corelocation Initialisation and Delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I have seen a lot of tutorials of **CoreLocation** and all of them are initialising and setting as delegate the **MainViewController**. It doesn't feel right to me.
In my case I want to access the location-settings from other view controller. I know that I can have a reference on the **MainViewController** and set my settings but a singleton to manage the location wouldn't be a better solution for managing the **CoreLocation**?(In my case I am using Significant change location and I am monitoring regions).

Comment: Tutorials are about using a feature, object, class. They are often not relevant to the architecture of "real apps". A singleton in your case seems quite a good solution. You could also use `NSNotification` to advertise updates, and if an object is "alive" and listens to it, it should update correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singleton to manage the location wouldn't be a better solution for managing the CoreLocation?

**Yes** Its much better option .

If you manage it by blocks its even better like [this](https://github.com/axldyb/CLLocationManager-blocks).